# Center text vertically in LinearLayout

Tags: android

If you look at [this](http://prntscr.com/83qdho) picture you'll see immediatly where is my problem. I'd like the flags' names to be vertically aligned with the picture, like this:

[image]

I have found a few answers around but I still cannot solve my problem. This is the xml code of the **main** page (where you can find the list view).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

This file is called **simplerow.xml** and it contains the layout that I have to apply to the ListVeiw.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/gametitle"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"  >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

If needed, this is the code that adds the flags/names to the ListView.

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(view.getContext(), aList, R.layout.simplerow, from, to);

// Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file
ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);

// Setting the adapter to the listView
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Despite the LinearLayout has `android:orientation="vertical"` and `android:gravity="center_vertical"` setted, the names aren't vertically centered. What could I do?

Comment: because your linear layout is messing up, try changing its height to `android:layout_height="match_parent"` instead of `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/flag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/gametitle"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
         />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It works now, I understood where was the problem! :)

Answer (score 1):

add `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` in your text view.

or user this in your main layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/e" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#FF9900" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

`android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` is want you need. It will center the LinearLayout in it's parent and then the `android:gravity="center_vertical"` will center the TextView. So convert your LinearLayout to this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/gametitle"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting layout_gravity of the linearlayout to centervertical.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"  >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    />
```